# How to create a proper start button on typing game using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a start button for my Javascript game that starts the and when the game is over resets the game. As of right now, the button I have starts the game but when it's "Game Over" the timer doesn't reset or start. The words change but not the timer or score. I tried using the reload.location and it didn't do anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
<title>One Piece WordBeater</title>
</head>
<body>
    <body class="bg-dark text-white">
        <header class="bg-secondary text-center p-3 mb-5">
            <h1>One Piece Word Beater</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <!--Word & Input-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">
                    <p class="lead">Current Level: <span class="text-info" id="levels"></span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                    <p class="lead">Type the Given Word Within <span class="text-success" id="seconds">5</span> Seconds. </p>
                    <h2 class="display-2 mb-5" id="current-word">luffy</h2>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Start Typing..." id="word-input" autofocus>
                    <h4 class="mt-3" id="message"></h4>
                    <br>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mr-5" id="start"><b>Let's Play!</b></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="reset"><b>Reset Game</b></button>
                    </div>
               </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">
                        <p class="lead">High Score: <span class="text-info" id="highsocre"></span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Time and Columns-->
            <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="col md-6">
                    <h3>Time left: <span id="time">0</span></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col md-6">
                    <h3>Score: <span id="score"> 0 </span></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Instructions-->
            <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="col md-12">
                    <div class="card card-body bg-secondary text-white">
                        <h5>Instructions</h5>
                        <p>Type each word in the given amount of seconds to score. To play again, just type the current word. Your score
                         will reset</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Level Selector-->
            <div class = "row mt-5">
                <div class="col md-12">
                    <div class="card card-body bg-secondary text-white">
                        <h5>Select the Difficulty</h5>
                       <div class="row mt-5">
                            <div class="col md-12">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-2" id="easy">Easy</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" id="medium">Medium</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="hard">Hard</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', init,);



//Avaible levels
const levels = {
    easy: 5,
    medium: 3,
    hard: 2,
}

//to cchange level
const currentLevel = levels.easy;

let time = currentLevel;
let score = 0;
let isPLaying;//initalzies game...true if game is on false if game is off


/*function resetGame(){
    const resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset')
    resetBtn.onclick = function() {
        let time = currentLevel;
        let score = 0;
        let isPLaying;   //Show number of seconds
    }
}*/


//DOM Elements
const wordInput = document.querySelector('#word-input');
const currentWord = document.querySelector('#current-word');
const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('#time');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const seconds = document.querySelector('#seconds');
const levelDisplay = document.querySelector('#levels');



const words = [
    'luffy',
    'zoro',
    'shanks',
    'nami',
    'brook',
    'chooper',
    'sanji',
    'franky',
    'jinbe',
    'carrot',
    'pekoms',
    'ace',
    'sabo',
    'robin',
    'bellamy',
    'crocodile',
    'merry',
    'yonko',
    'camie',
    'nefertari',
    'raizo',
    'momo',
    'law',
    'dracule',
    'boa',
    'buggy',
    'golroger',
    'bigmom',
    'smoker',
    'kaido'
];

//initialize Game

 /*function init() {
//     //Show number of seconds
    seconds.innerHTML = currentLevel;
//     //load a word from array
     showWord(words);
//     //Start Matching on word input
     wordInput.addEventListener('input', startMatch);
//     //Call countdown every second
      setInterval(countdown, 1000);
//     //Check status
      setInterval(checkStatus, 50)
 } */

 function init() {
    //start button
    const startBtn = document.getElementById('start')
    startBtn.onclick = function() {
            //Show number of seconds
    seconds.innerHTML = currentLevel;
    //load a word from array
    showWord(words);
    //Start Matching on word input
    wordInput.addEventListener('input', startMatch);
    //Call countdown every second
    setInterval(countdown, 1000);
    //Check status
    setInterval(checkStatus, 50)
    }
}


//level Buttons

//Easy Mode
// document.getElementById('easy').addEventListener('click', easyMode);
// function easyMode(levels) {

// }

//Start Match
//converts words to lowercase

function startMatch() {
    if(matchWords()){
        isPLaying = true;
        time = currentLevel + 1;
        showWord(words);
        wordInput.value='';
        score++;
    }

    //if score negative -1 display 0
    if(score === -1){
        scoreDisplay.innerHTML = 0;
    }else{
        scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
    }

}
//Match Current Word to word imput

function matchWords(){
        if(wordInput.value.toLowerCase() === currentWord.innerHTML) {
        message.innerHTML = 'Correct!!!';
        return true;
    } else {
        message.innerHTML = '';
        return false;
    }
}

//Pick & Show random word
function showWord(words) {
    //Generate random array index
    const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    //Output random word
    currentWord.innerHTML = words[randIndex];
}
//Countdown Timer
function countdown() {
    //Make sure time is not run out
    if(time > 0) {
        //Decrease time
        time--;
    }else if(time === 0) {
        //Game Over
        isPLaying = false;
    }
    //Show time
    timeDisplay.innerHTML = time;
}

//Check game Status
function checkStatus() {

    if(!isPLaying && time === 0){
        message.innerHTML = 'Game Over!!';
        score = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timer doesn't reset because you didn't stop it with the clearInterval function. The score doesn't reset because you didn't change it in HTML.

First Of all to understang what is wrong with your timer add this code inside your checkStatus() function and open the developer console of your navigator. You will see that your timer continue even if the game is over.

```
console.log("The game is over but the timer continue...");
```

OK now, to fix you issue: add this to your code to keep a reference and use it later:

```
let countDownInterval;
let checkStatusCountDown;
```

modify your init() function with:

```
 countDownInterval = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
 checkStatusCountDown = setInterval(checkStatus, 50);
```

Now when the game is over we will clear the time interval and reset the score:

```
function checkStatus() {

 if(!isPLaying && time === 0){
    message.innerHTML = 'Game Over!!';
    score = -1;
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = 0; // reset score in html
    clearInterval(checkStatusCountDown); // clear interval
    clearInterval(countDownInterval); // clear interval
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did reworked init and changed the checkstatus(). It works only after a few seconds delay and then it won't reset itself again :/.

https://codepen.io/jnp0304/pen/moBwYo?editors=0110

Comment: Why did put the checkStatus() function beore the init function ?

Comment: Not sure how that got there, I'm going to fix that move it to the bottom.